# Parsing a Zipped (GZ) JSON file in PHP

Tags: php, json, decode, unzip

With help from the guys on Stackoverflow I can now Parse JSON code from a **file** and save a **'Value'** into a database

However the file I intend to read from is actually a massive 2GB file. My web server will not hold this file. However it will hold a ZIPPED version of it - ie 80MB.(ie .GZ)

I believe there is a way to PARSE JSON from a ZIPPED file (.GZ)..........Can anybody help?

I have found the below function which I believe will do this (I think) but I don't know how to link it to my code

```
private function uncompressFile($srcName, $dstName) {
$sfp = gzopen($srcName, "rb");
$fp = fopen($dstName, "w");
while ($string = gzread($sfp, 4096)) {
fwrite($fp, $string, strlen($string));
}
gzclose($sfp);
fclose($fp);
}
```

My current PHP code is below and works. It reads a basic small file, JSON decodes it (The JSON is in a series of separate lines hence the need for FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES) and then takes a value and saves to MySQL database.

However I believe I need to somehow combine these two bits of code so I can read a ZIPPED file without exceeding my 100MB storage on my webserver

```
$file="CIF_ALL_UPDATE_DAILY_toc-update-sun";

$trains = file($json_filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach ($trains as $train) {
$json=json_decode($train,true);

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

$input=$value['main_train_uid'];
$q="INSERT INTO railstptest (main_train_uid) VALUES ('$input')";
$r=mysqli_query($mysql_link,$q);
}
}   
}   
if (is_null($json)) {
die("Json decoding failed with error: ". json_last_error());
}
mysqli_close($mysql_link);
```

Many Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is a short snippet of the JSON . There are a series of these

I would only want to be getting a few key values. For example the value G90491 and P20328. A lot of the info I would not need

{"JsonAssociationV1":{"transaction_type":"Delete","main_train_uid":"G90491","assoc_train_uid":"G90525","assoc_start_date":"2013-09-07T00:00:00Z","location":"EDINBUR","base_location_suffix":null,"diagram_type":"T","CIF_stp_indicator":"O"}}
{"JsonAssociationV1":{"transaction_type":"Delete","main_train_uid":"P20328","assoc_train_uid":"P21318","assoc_start_date":"2013-08-23T00:00:00Z","location":"MARYLBN","base_location_suffix":null,"diagram_type":"T","CIF_stp_indicator":"C"}}

Comment: So this is a .ZIP file, not a .GZ (gzip) file?

Comment: you can't parse without extracting. that does never works with compressed data.

Comment: a json file has no concept of separate lines.

Comment: @hakre: In the original code, each line is decoded as an entirely separate JSON string. So the entire file would not have to be in memory at once.

Comment: Just a little question back: *"I believe there is a way to PARSE JSON from a ZIPPED file without actually having to save the 2GB version of the file"* - What makes you believing so? (and actually Stackoverflow is about programming questions, not about believings which tend to be religous). (same applies to the further believings of you, but I'm fine if you answer just for the first for the moment)

Comment: The file is a .GZ file. I have saved the ZIPPED file (80MB) in my web saver. My question is confusing - sorry. I am seeking a solution that uses my current code but reads from a .GZ file. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible to do stream extraction of the file and then use a stream JSON parser.  `ZipArchive` has `getStream`, and someone [created a streaming JSON parser for PHP](https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser).

You will have to write a listener that inserts the database values as they are found and discards unnecessary JSON so it does not consume memory.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open("file.zip");
$parser = new JsonStreamingParser_Parser($zip->getStream("file.json"),
    new DB_Value_Inserter);
$parser->parse();
```

Based on your question, you're working with gzip instead of zip.  To get the stream  you can use

```
fopen("compress.zlib://path/to/file.json", "r");
```

It's difficult to write the `DB_Value_Inserter` since you haven't provided the format of the JSON you need, but it seems like you can probably just override the `Listener::value` method and just write the string values you receive.

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills . I have edited in a snippet of the JSON. You are right. I would only be looking for a few of the values within the JSON. A lot of the JSON 95% will not be needed. Any help you can provide as I am very new to PHP. I am using a .GZ file. Thanks

Comment: Is there a way of reading and parsing the JSON in line by line (you will see the structure could allow for that) - ie only retain in memory the current line of JSON? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP has [compression wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php) that can help with opening and reading lines from compressed files. One is for reading gzip files:

```
$gzipFile = 'CIF_ALL_UPDATE_DAILY_toc-update-sun.gz';
$trains = new SplFileObject("compress.zlib://{$gzipFile}", 'r');
$trains->setFlags(SplFileObject::DROP_NEW_LINE | SplFileObject::READ_AHEAD
    | SplFileObject::SKIP_EMPTY);
```

Because [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php) is iterable, you can keep your outer `foreach` loop the way it is. Of course, [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets) remains an alternative to using `SplFileObject`.

Comment: Thanks Pleasestand. It works well for the smaller .GZ files but I am running out of memory on the 80MB zipped file. Would that be the web server running out of memory?

Comment: @user2635961: What error message are you getting? At least on PHP 5.4.6, I haven't managed to reproduce a memory leak.

Comment: PleaseStand: It runs fine for a number of loops. Then repeats saying there is a Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() before ending with Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 65798144) (tried to allocate 65014721 bytes) in .......The script works fine on small .GZ files of JSON. Its just when I apply it to the bigger files. I think I need to read a line at a time. I also should add I am running the script through an IE10 browser.

Comment: PleaseStand: Further to the above the browser shows a broken page in the URL